# slideDown menubar slides down other document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I made a menubar using a `<div>` tag. When it is clicked the `<div>` below it slides down, and another content below those two `<div>`'s should stay in its place, but it goes down too.

You can see  picture here

[image]

As you see in this picture when I click to slide down `<div>` , the other `<div>` in bottom of that goes down too. How to fix it?

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide">click to slide down</div>
<div id="panel">Hello! this is my first slide down example.</div>
<div>this is another div</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slide{
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px #101010;
    width:500px;
    height:30px;
    background:#cccccc;
}
#panel{
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px #101010;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    display:none;
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slide').click(function(){
    $('#panel').stop().slideToggle(570);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML/CSS? You probably don't want to keep your second div within the flow of the page, but are doing.

Comment: sry i am new in stackoverflow see code here : http://shrib.com/menubarproblem

Comment: The solution is giving `#panel` `position:absolute;` and put it inside a container with `position:relative`. That way the panel won't move down other content below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a few `position` changes in your CSS, and place your second `<div>` *inside* your first. `top:100%` mean's that your second div will animate from the bottom of your first div:

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide">click to slide down
    <div id="panel">Hello! this is my first slide down example.</div>
</div>

<div>this is another div</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slide{
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px #101010;
    width:500px;
    height:30px;
    background:#cccccc;
    position:relative;
}
#panel{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px #101010;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:none;
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NUH2T/)

Comment: what does "box-sizing:border-box;" mean?

Comment: It is explained fully here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing but when set to `border-box`, the width will take border and padding into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu_container">
    <div id="slide">click to slide down</div>
    <div id="panel">Hello! this is my first slide down example.</div>
</div>

<div>this is another div</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu_container { position:relative; }
#panel { position:absolute; top:100%; left:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
#panel{
text-align:center;
border:solid 1px #101010;
width:500px;
height:200px;
display:none;
background:#ff0000;
z-index: 10;
position: absolute;
}
```